# Appending tuples to lists, assigning index

Tags: python, list, append, tuples

I'm working on a chemistry program which requires a list of all elements and their corresponding atomic mass units, something along the lines of:

```
Elements = [(H,1),(He,2)...(C,12)]
```

all the elements and their AMU are read from a file where each line is written like "C 12". I need to read the information from the file, append each line into its own tuple and then append the tuple to a list. Here's some code I've tried without success.

```
class chemistry:
    def readAMU():
        infil = open("AtomAMU.txt", "r")
        line = infil.readline()
        Atoms = list()
        Element = ()
        while line !="":
            line = line.rstrip("\n")
            parts = line.split(" ");
            element = parts[0]
            AMU = parts[1]
            element.append(Element)
            AMU.append(Element)
            Element.append(Atoms)
```

Am I on the right track? If no, how would I append two values into a tuple, assign each value and index and then append this into a list?

Comment: You can format your code by selecting it and clicking the '{ }' icon.

Comment: Tuples are immutable. You can't `append()` anything to them, you have to fully specify their contents when creating them.

Comment: @rmmh Just fixed that; C is bad enough to read as regular text, but Python without indentation is masochistic.

Comment: You really just made the code a lot more complex than it needed to be.  You don't need a class or a definiton - unless you are planning on pulling in more data or reusing the definition.  You also didn't need to create so many smaller arrays.  I'd suggest looking at the solutions given and really trying to understand what was done.

Answer (score 5):

An easier solution is to iterate over the file using a for loop:

```
elements = []
with open("AtomAMU.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        name, mass = line.split()
        elements.append((name, int(mass)))
```

Comment: I have such mixed feelings when I see a question like this ... 10-15 minutes of reading some documentation on Python.org or Google would have answered the question. I realize this is a help site, but a little bit of effort before-hand would have eliminated the need to ask in the first place. I smell homework assignment ...

Comment: @Will:  This person put forth the effort to write code that almost works.  I'm happy to answer those.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski True enough; I've seen worse than this before. I guess there are times when I simply get the feeling that little, if any, effort has been made before posting. Perhaps I feel that I put forth more effort than others (I try not to ask unless I'm really stuck) and so I judge a little more harshly than I should. Like I said, such posts give me mixed feelings, that's all.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the lines only contain `C 12` and such, and are separated by spaces:

```
result = []
for line in open('filename.txt'):
    result.append(line.split())
```

Or if you happen to like list comprehensions:

```
[l.split() for l in open('filename.txt')]
```

Note that I assume that you didn't care if it was a tuple or a list. If so, just cast it:

```
[tuple(l.split()) for l in open('filename.txt')]
```

Edit: thanks, Steven.

Comment: This code is incorrect.  It will still contain newlines and the items in the list will be lists, not tuples.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: why is this incorrect? I updated the answer to remove the `readlines` call, but the tuple casting and splitting work as they should in my opinion?

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary would be a better data structure.

```
with open("AtomAMU.txt") as f:
    elements_amu = dict(line.split() for line in f)
```

Use it like this:

```
elements_amu['H']   # gets AMU for H
elements_amu.keys() # list of elements without AMU
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class demonstrates that you're new to Python, so I'll try to clean it up and point out some things without completely rewriting it. Other solutions here are cleaner, but hopefully this will help you understand some of the concepts.

```
class chemistry:
    # Because this is a class method, it will automatically
    # receive a reference to the instance when you call the
    # method. You have to account for that when declaring
    # the method, and the standard name for it is `self`
    def readAMU(self):
        infil = open("AtomAMU.txt", "r")
        line = infil.readline()
        Atoms = list()
        # As Frédéric said, tuples are immutable (which means
        # they can't be changed). This means that an empty tuple
        # can never be added to later in the program. Therefore,
        # you can leave the next line out.
        # Element = ()
        while line !="":
            line = line.rstrip("\n")
            parts = line.split(" ");
            element = parts[0]
            AMU = parts[1]
            # The next several lines indicate that you've got the
            # right idea, but you've got the method calls reversed.
            # If this were to work, you would want to reverse which
            # object's `append()` method was getting called.
            # 
            # Original:
            # element.append(Element)
            # AMU.append(Element)
            # Element.append(Atoms)
            # 
            # Correct:
            Element = (element, AMU)
            Atoms.append(Element)
        # If you don't make sure that `Atoms` is a part of `self`,
        # all of the work will disappear at the end of the method
        # and you won't be able to do anything with it later!
        self.Atoms = Atoms
```

Now, when you want to load the atomic numbers you can instantiate the `chemistry` class and call its `readAMU()` method!

```
>>> c = chemistry()
>>> c.readAMU()
>>> print c.Atoms
```

Remember, `Atoms` is a part of the `c` instance because of the last line: `self.Atoms = Atoms`.

Answer (score 0):

enjoy.

```
elementlist= []
datafile= open("AtomAMU.txt")
for elementdata in datafile:
    elementlist.append(elementdata.split(" "))
```

Comment: does not work ... readfile is assigned the value of the first line of text in "AtomAMU.txt", and the file is closed. Drop the call to readline() in that line and it works.

Comment: woops. Iv changed it. Thanks btw.

Comment: no problem; something easy to overlook when throwing code together quickly.